# Question list stops being expanded when switching to new tab from home page

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

When I go to the home page of either SO or Meta (i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/), it shows all the questions in the expanded view. From there, if I click on any tab (other than home) it switches to the collapsed view, instead of staying in expanded view. I think the intended behavior is that the expanded state remains consistent as you navigate (since that's how every other page transition seems to behave)

It only happens when switching from the home tab to another tab, and only if I navigated directly to the home page. This happens reliably for me every time I follow these steps.

For example,

- Go to https://stackoverflow.com/ - shows expanded view
- Click on another tab - shows collapsed view
- Switch back to expanded view
- Click on home tab - stays in expanded view
- Click on another tab - stays in expanded view

Home Page:

[image]

---

After selecting another tab:

[image]

Comment: are you using more than one browser tab? I can't repro this behavior

Comment: @EbenezerSklivvze I'm only using one tab. It happens for me 100% of the time, tested in Firefox, Chrome and IE.

Comment: I just reproed, there are some weird conditions needed to make it happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed and it will be deployed in `rev 2015.12.17.3997` (meta) and `rev 2015.12.17.3103` (main).